# Forecasting Time series data using ARIMA model when data contains only HH:MM:SS in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, arima

I have a Dataframe that contains Time as index in the format of HH:MM:SS. The dataframe has only one column say Y which contains a float value.
My Data set is :

```html
09:37:57            121
09:39:05             73
09:40:40             91
09:40:45            101
09:47:40             69
09:52:13             81
09:58:35             83
10:00:30            428
10:11:28            184
10:13:20            231
10:14:18            577
10:19:44             92
10:23:17             67
10:23:40            156
10:24:21             76
10:24:31             95
10:26:38            180
10:26:43             65
10:27:11            130
10:28:28             90
10:29:53            293
10:31:26            132
10:36:21             67
10:38:22            118
10:39:37            110
10:41:03             65
10:43:49             71
10:43:57             90
10:45:17             93
10:45:44             74
```

I want to forecast Y value using ARIMA MODEL of (2,1,2) order. But I am getting the following error:

```html
 model = ARIMA(endog=dt, order=(2, 1, 2))
  File "C:\Users\Moushmi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 1000, in __new__
    mod.__init__(endog, order, exog, dates, freq, missing)
  File "C:\Users\Moushmi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 1015, in __init__
    super(ARIMA, self).__init__(endog, (p, q), exog, dates, freq, missing)
  File "C:\Users\Moushmi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 452, in __init__
    super(ARMA, self).__init__(endog, exog, dates, freq, missing=missing)
  File "C:\Users\Moushmi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py", line 44, in __init__
    self._init_dates(dates, freq)
  File "C:\Users\Moushmi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py", line 56, in _init_dates
    dates = to_datetime(dates)
  File "C:\Users\Moushmi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 514, in to_datetime
    result = _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name=arg.name)
  File "C:\Users\Moushmi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 435, in _convert_listlike
    require_iso8601=require_iso8601
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 2355, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas\_libs\tslib.c:46617)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 2583, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas\_libs\tslib.c:46321)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 2516, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas\_libs\tslib.c:45268)
TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime
```

My code is :

```
model = ARIMA(endog=dt, order=(2, 1, 2))
```

results_ARIMA = model.fit()
print(results_ARIMA)
plt.plot(model.resid)
plt.show()

Here **dt** is the dataframe. Suggestion is required to solve the issue.
I problem is very similar to this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003158/arima-modeling-on-time-series-dataframe-python?rq=1) But there is no solution.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Thank you for the explanation of the error. I have changed my dataframe index from time to datetime. And it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you have to understand the error message.
Firstly, you have a series of time objects, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(pd.datetime(2017, 5, 3, 11,11,11).time())

0    11:11:11
dtype: object
```

now let's try to convert it into datetime

```
pd.to_datetime(s)
```

This provides the same error message as you have

```
pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime 
(pandas\_libs\tslib.c:46617)()

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime 
(pandas\_libs\tslib.c:46321)()

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime 
(pandas\_libs\tslib.c:45268)()

TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime
```

So, not surprisingly, we can't convert a time object into a datetime object since the datepart is completely missing. Essentially, you need to provide some dates there.